# Strongly Continuous Semigroups

Tags: operator-theory, semigroup-of-operators, unbounded-operators

I have a question concerning strongly continuous semigroups and applications to PDE.
A strongly continuous semigroup on a Banach space $X$ is a map $T: \mathbb{R}_+ \rightarrow L(X)$ such that:

(1) $T(0)=id$

(2) $\forall t,s \geq 0$: $T(t+s)=T(t)T(s)$

(3) $\forall x_0\in X: \| T(t)x_0 - x_0 \| \rightarrow 0, \text{as } t\downarrow 0$.

(cf. Wikipedia)

I am interested in the applications of semigroups to PDEs of the type
\begin{equation}
u_t-Au=f
\end{equation}

My question is: Why is the convergence in the 3rd condition the "right" convergence to claim? Stronger convergence limits us to bounded operators as generators, but why do we claim this convergence?

Thank you in advance!

Best,
Luke

Comment: is there any other types of convergences?

Comment: One could for example consider convergence in the weak operator topology, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_operator_topology

Comment: I think, if you take for example $f=0$, that is, the equation $x'=Ax$, a strong solution satisfies $x(t)=T(t)x_0$. Thus we can define mild solutions those that satisfy this equality. Those solutions are not necessarily differentialble. In a lot of PDEs the map $t\mapsto T(t)x_0$ is continuous. This gives the semigroup a lot of nice properties. But in other cases, $t\mapsto T(t)x_0$ is not continuous. I think, this opens the field for a new class of semigroups. I don't know if such semigroups are well studied or not. Did you check the book of Engel and Nagel?

Comment: I have not checked Engel-Nagel yet. But actually I found a remark in the bibliographical notes in the book "Semigroups of Linear Operators and Applications to PDEs" by Pazy. He writes: "In the present book we deal only with strongly continuous semigroups. Different classes of continuity at zero were introduced and studied in Hille-Phillips. (...)". He also mentions other references. I will check those when I find the time. Thank you for your replies!